# Python numpy concatenate 4D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to concatenate 2 numpy arrays of features predicted by the convolution layers in a vgg16 model.

Basically i have used the bottom layers of a vgg16 model to predict the features for my full dataset and now I want to load the parts of dataset dynamically based on some settings, to train some models with it.

So, I have 2 array of shape: 
    `(724, 512, 6, 8)` and `(3376, 512, 6, 8)`
 Basically the first one contains features predicted from 724 image files (each prediction has shape `(512, 6, 8)`).
I want to concatenate these 2 arrays into one of shape `(4100, 512, 6, 8)`

I have tried using:

`np.array([np.concatenate(arr, axis=0) for arr in false_train_list])`

where false_train_list is the list containing the 2 arrays with the above shapes.

Also tried with np.stack, tf.stack...
All of these result in an array with shape (2,)

Can someone explain why ? I haven't found any good resources to understand how exactly np.concatenate() works..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply need this instead:

```
np.concatenate(false_train_list, axis=0)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: Wow, that is true.
Why does this work and 
`np.array([np.concatenate(arr, axis=0) for arr in false_train_list])`
does not though ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am just starting up with python. 
I would've thought that `[np.concatenate(arr, axis=0) for arr in false_train_list]` would simply try to concatenate all arrays in my list on axis 0.
`np.concatenate(false_train_list, axis=0)` looks pretty much the same to me... Can you please briefly explain what is different ? Nothing from the docs gives me any hint about the differences :) Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: The first argument of `concatenate` is the list of arrays to concatenate, in `[np.concatenate(arr, axis=0) for arr in false_train_list]` you iterate over your 2 arrays and pass each of them to `concatenate` separately, so you effectively concatenate all rows of each sub-array (a single array is interpreted as a list of rows, try `np.concatenate(np.eye(5), axis=0)` to see what this is doing), then put both results in a list. Not at all the same.

Comment: @SorinPanduru.  'pretty much' doesn't count in programming.  One passes a whole list to `concatenate`, the other passes one element of the list at time, and collects the result in a new list.  You may need to play around with simpler lists and list comprehensions.